# Fortran compiler in ARM/Android

Tags: android, compilation, arm, fortran, gfortran

Is there a Fortran compiler for Android OS running machines. I have found there are some Fortran to C translators which would then compile in C, but I would like to know if there are compilers like gfortran for ARM/RISC machines or for Android OS.

Comment: I want to develop the code in Android OS on an ARM machine, cross compiling is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you mean I have root privileges?

Comment: Yes, I would aim at an Android that would grand root login.

Comment: Hi, I already mentioned in the comments that cross compiling is not what I am looking for. I want to run the code in an Android OS on an ARM machine.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to have your Fotran code run in Android, with a big BUT!  To my knowledge, there is not an explicit Android (and in particular) ARM target Fortran compiler that would do all things I would imagine necessary (but see the PS below) ... and I have not looked into it for a couple of years.

However, you can build your own Android/Fortran apk's, and it definitely works.

There a variety of approaches, but the most successful/least painful (to my knowledge) is to create your own cross-compile ARM/Fortran tool-chain on Linux with GCC/gFortran (or even via a "virtual" Linux running on Windows).  You may need to get an older version of the ADT (Android Development Tool) combined with Eclipse Photran.  I have not tried it with newer versions or with AndroidStudio, etc.

It is a non-trivial task to create such a tool-chain.  You need to learn also to programme in Java for the "front end", and to programme Android JNI/NDK etc to link the (ARM Fortran executables/libs).  My suggestion is for your first Apk to be a pure Android/Java apk, before moving on to Fortran/C etc JNI linked machinery.

The best place to start, and the two people who deserver the most, if not virtually all, the credit (AFIK), are here

http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.ca/2013/02/how-to-build-gcc-fortran-cross-compiler.html  (Danilo Giulianelli)

and here

http://specificimpulses.blogspot.ca/2011/01/my-android-speaks-fortran-yours-can-too.html (Mike Long)

... they did all the "heavy lifting".

I have used their results, and created various Fortran based app's/apk's that run blindingly fast on a SmartPhone/Tablet.  I have benchmarked some obvious tests, such as Fortran, C, and Java based versions of the LinPack benchmark ... not surprisingly, Fortran wins.  C is slightly slower.  While Java is way way behind in execution speed (as one would expect).

PS.  I have seen adverts for explicit Fortran compilers that are supposed to run directly on Android (e.g. on GooglePlay/Store), but I have not tried those myself as my (preliminary) research suggested those would be a non-starter for my needs.  Perhaps those might work for you.  If they do, please post a comment back.